# How do I use \renewcommand to get BACK my greek letters?

Tags: latex, renewcommand

I'm a LaTeX newbie, but I've been doing my homework, and now I have a question that I can't seem to find the answer to.
I create the definition of an equation, let's just say it's this one:

```
The potential is characterized by a length $\sigma$ and an energy $\epsilon$.
```

In reality, this equation is more complex, which is why I wanted to try a shortcut. If my equation were this simplistic, I wouldn't try my substitution technique.
I use the \renewcommand to save me some time:

```
\renewcommand{\sigma}{1}
```

And this works fabulously and will replace all instances of sigma with 1. Unfortunately though, since \sigma has a global scope, I need to reset it.
I tried a couple different ways:
Attempt 1: -deadlock due to circular reference?

```
\newcommand{\holdsigma}{\sigma}
\renewcommand{\sigma}{1}
The potential is characterized by a length $\sigma$ and an energy $\epsilon$.
\renewcommand{\sigma}{\holdsigma}
```

I would think to reset the command, it should look something like this:

```
\renewcommand{\sigma}{\greek{\sigma}}
```

but that obviously hasn't worked out for me.
Any idea about how the greek letters are originally defined in the language?

Comment: Don't forget about http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This seems like a really bad idea. You'll have to flip the definition of `\sigma` back and forth any time you need to use it. You can't edit the equation(s) and use a `\mysigma` or something?

Comment: I thought about that, and that's probably what I'll end up doing, but for future reference, I wanted to know if it was possible to flip back and forth.

Comment: I'm sorry Gabe, I didn't realize that there was a teX site. Should I repost over there?

Comment: @chrisbster: No, the [consensus](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12918/can-we-have-a-ruling-on-latex-on-stack-overflow) was that LaTeX questions are often programming-related (like here, which is about how to find the definition of a command in the language and redefine it) — more so than many CSS questions anyway! — so it's fine to ask them here. It's just that you're more likely to get faster and better answers on the dedicated tex.stackexchange community.

Comment: Do not ask "how do I use X to do Y in Z?"  Ask "how do I do Y in Z?"

Comment: @Svante: Sometimes it's nice to know, specifically, whether one was on the right lines with `X`; whether one had successfully come up with a reasonable solution on his/her own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find out how `\sigma` or any other command is originally defined, you can use `\show\sigma`. (The answer is that `\sigma` is defined as `\mathchar"11B`.) You can type this either in your document itself — compilation will pause and you can type Enter after reading the reply — or you can type this in TeX/LaTeX's interactive mode.

Example with a document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
What is $\sigma$?          % Prints "What is σ" in the DVI/PS/PDF.
\show\sigma                % Prints "> \sigma=\mathchar"11B." in the compilation.
Now that we know, let us redefine it.
\renewcommand{\sigma}{1}
Now it is: $\sigma$.       % Prints "Now it is: 1." in the DVI/PS/PDF.
OK, let's go back.
\renewcommand{\sigma}{\mathchar"11B}
We again have: $\sigma$.   %Prints "We again have: σ." in the DVI/PS/PDF.
\end{document}
```

Or else at the command prompt, type `latex`, then type `\relax`, then type `\show\sigma`, read what it says, then type `x` to exit.

Answer (score 12):

I have to admit that I don't understand why you want to do what you're asking, but this should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Before redefinition, \verb|\sigma| looks like $\sigma$.

% Copy the current definition of \sigma to \oldsigma
\let\oldsigma\sigma

% Redefine \sigma to be '1'
\renewcommand{\sigma}{1}

After redefinition, \verb|\sigma| looks like $\sigma$.

You can still use \verb|\oldsigma| if you want to use the original definition $\oldsigma$.

% Restore the original definition of \sigma
\let\sigma\oldsigma

Now \verb|\sigma| is back to its normal appearance $\sigma$.

\end{document}
```